# How Do I Open Fixed Window In Firefox (like Chrome app mode)?

Tags: firefox

I'm essentially wanting to create a desktop shortcut to open a window of Firefox without tabs, locked address bar, no menu, etc.

Similar to what some pop ups look like or what Chromium Desktop Apps look like.

What options can I use to accomplish this from the command line?

Comment: I wasn't quite sure you wanted - so I went on the 'like Chromium Desktop apps' bit.

Comment: Your answer shows exactly what I am after, thanks.  I'll give it a shot in a bit.

Comment: See also: http://eudennis.tumblr.com/post/123744218866/create-separated-instances-with-icon-for-firefox (from euDennis's answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have an easier way I usually do this. It works with a stock Firefox installation without any customization. You can even change the height and width of the window.

The command:

```
firefox -url 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>window.open("http://google.com", "_blank","height=400,width=600,menubar=no,location=no,toolbar=no,left=100,top=100")<%2Fscript><%2Fbody><%2Fhtml>'
```

Just change `http://google.com` to the URL. You can also change the height and width variables (in pixels).

Comment: Works great :) just need to sort popup blocker settings

Comment: you can add `,scrollbars=yes` to allow the popup to have scroll bars.

Comment: You can add it as a bookmarklet: `javascript:(function(){window.open("http://google.com", "_blank","height=400,width=600,menubar=no,location=no,toolbar=no,left=100,top=100");})();`

Comment: Looks like this no longer works after Firefox 57 was released

Answer (score 29):

I was looking for something like this for a while, so here is how I made my own Firefox 'app' mode.

<sup>For Googlenauts with Windows/Mac '*Set Up Firefox*' & '*Alternatively...*' should also work on other OSs, perhaps with a few tweaks to the [commands](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) used, whilst '*Create Launcher*' should work only for most Desktop Environments that implement the [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) '[specifactions](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/)'.</sup>

### Set Up Firefox

First run `firefox --ProfileManager` from terminal *(you may need to close any running instances of Firefox first, or use the `-new-instance` option)*.
Create a new profile and call it `app`. Select the 'Default' one *(**IMPORTANT:** otherwise by default it will start the app profile you are creating)* and press 'Exit'.

[image: Firefox Profile Manager]

Now run `firefox -P app`. This will start Firefox from the new `app` profile you just created. As removing the tabs and navigation bar is now difficult or impossible in Firefox's settings, you will need to install some extensions to remove them - these ones work, though may be better ones available that hide the bars permanently:

- [Hide Tab bar with one Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-tab-bar-with-one-tab/) - hides the tab bar when there is only one tab open.
- [Hide Navigation Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar) - you need to press <kbd>F2</kbd> to show/hide the nav bar

***Edit:*** Both options of hiding the tab+nav bars is also included with [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer) - small icons can also be set for a more compact layout.

Now, when you run `firefox -P app -new-instance http://URL` (e.g. `firefox -P app -new-instance https://askubuntu.com/q/487936/178596`), you should get a Firefox window like this:
[image: Firefox window with only title bar]

Also, when you open Firefox by running `firefox` or clicking the Firefox button, it should open your normal Firefox profile with the tab and nav bars.

Works in Firefox 30.0, 40.0, partially tested in 52.

### Create Launcher

You probably want to create a launcher to open your app from the menu - you can do so using this template:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<APP NAME>
GenericName=<APP NAME>
#Comment=Browse the Web
Exec=firefox -P app -new-instance <https://URL>
Icon=<ICON>
Terminal=false
Type=Application
#MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
#Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Keywords=<KEYWORDS>
```

Where:

- `<APP NAME>` is the name of your app
- `<https://URL>` is the URL you want shown by default on launching the app. `-new-instance` is optional but allows the Firefox App to be run as the same time as normal Firefox. See also: [Mozilla Developer - Command Line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) and the output of `firefox --help`.
- `<ICON>` is the name of a icon `/usr/share/icons` or `~/.local/share/icons`, or the path to a icon file (preferably PNG or SVG I think).
- `<KEYWORDS>` - Relevant keywords delimited by `;`, you can include words you can use to search for the launcher in the Dash/Menu - e.g. `Paper;Ink;Toner;` - *Optional*: comment it out with a `#` at the beginning of the line if you don't use this.

For more info on how .desktop files work, you can read [this](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys)

---

You can also follow both above steps, and create various different app profiles, just remember if you use a different name to `app` - e.g. `gmailapp`, you need to use that name consistently instead of `app`.

Also, I'm not sure the `-new-instance` option is needed much any more, I have left it in anyway.

See also:
 - https://superuser.com/questions/468580/create-application-shortcut-chromes-feature-in-firefox

### Alternatively...

I was looking for a solution to create a script so I could run a command and create Firefox apps (so without extensions etc), and the following [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes) works well at hiding all the toolbars:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
#TabsToolbar,
#PersonalToolbar,
#BookmarksToolbar,
#MenuToolbar,
#tabbrowser-tabs,
#nav-bar,
#TabsToolbar { display: none !important; }
```

I haven't tested it too much yet, thought it will be annoying to use since it hides all the open tabs....

Comment: There’s still a white 1-pixel-wide horizontal bar on top of the window – both when I use an extension and when I apply your `userChrome.css`. Have you run across this before?

Comment: Don't think so, what theme/desktop are you using?

Comment: I’m using Gnome 3.18 with the default shell theme and Firefox 45.0.1 with the default theme. I have a custom GTK theme applied – but I don’t think it’s relevant since a stripe like this doesn’t appear in any other app. Compare [`firefox -P app`](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1459802340.png) to [`google-chrome --app`](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1459802450.png).

Comment: Thanks. The userChrome.css option provided a quick and simple solution for me. The only obvious issue is that the downloads icon is now hidden.

Comment: Those two extensions don't appear to exist anymore

Comment: a working way for a MacOS would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

Firefox 73+ has Site-Specific Browsers: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283670

- First set `browser.ssb.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`.
- Then call your app with `-ssb` instead of `-url`.

For example:

```
firefox -ssb https://www.youtube.com
```

opens YouTube in this mode.

Comment: It may be helpful to also provide a full command example, as opposed to specifying the option to use for the command.

Comment: how to create a shortcut with this? and is possible to have a different icon?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa I polished up an answer to that here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1364545/307091

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of that Bugzilla thread, it seems like `-ssb` is not a feature yet/any_more. Also, it doesn't seem to work for me on Firefox 92.0 (64-bit).

Comment: Note that this feature has been removed, as of Firefox 86+: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1682593

Answer (score 4):

## Kiosk mode

Similar, but not exactly the same is [**kiosk mode**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode):

```
firefox -kiosk -new-window https://yourwebapplication.whatever
```

In this mode, input options will be partially limited (e.g. no right-click context menu). Otherwise your addons still work and you can change the current address by reaching for the hidden address bar with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd>. Your sessions and cookies will also be kept the same. If you wish to avoid that use:

```
firefox --kiosk --private-window https://yourwebapplication.whatever
```

#### Exiting fullscreen

- Your window manager might let you bind a global shortcut key to toggle fullscreen for any application.
- Your window manager might have a window operations menu from which to control fullscreen (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for KDE).
- To accomplish this from a terminal window or script you can use e.g. `wmctrl`:

```
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -b toggle,fullscreen
```

- Many other GUI and CLI (i.e. terminal) tools might help you as well here.

#### Getting the content to be 100% of the non-fullscreen window

Next, you might want to remove the window border (also with a global keybinding or from the window operations menu.

The last barrier left might be hiding toolbars and such. You can toggle those off:

- from the menubar - reached with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then arrow keys.
- with keybindings if they have any - e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for the bookmark toolbar; or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for the history sidebar;

Comment: Kiosk mode takes over the whole screen - it can't run in a window.

Comment: Kiosk model is typically a locked down mode where several features are disabled like right-click, keyboard shortcuts and anything that might allow escaping or exiting the "kiosk".  In "App mode", the user is still trusted to use most features the browser offers.

Comment: @AndyForceno if you use a separate profile with -P and --no-remote and possible --class it'll open a separate instance

Comment: @ChrisL.Barnes There are some workarounds. See the updated answer.

Comment: @AndyForceno That was due to a missing parameter - see the first command of the updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Since [geek1011's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/811657/285898) doesn't work after Firefox 57, here's my solution:

I wrote a small piece of code to create an application window, and present a list of webapps based on a custom-defined list. Copy the code [I posted here](https://bitbucket.org/amitkeret/userscripts/src/master/firefox-webapps.bookmarklet.js), then create a bookmerklet that points to: `javascript:[paste code here]`.

Just customise the details in the `appList` object to match your needs.

Note you still need to configure Firefox as explained [in ADTC's answer](https://superuser.com/a/937210/903485) to allow `window.open` to create tab-less, toolbar-less, scrollbar-less windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to download these extensions for Firefox:

   - [Popup Window](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popup-window/)
   - [Web app Mode](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-app-mode/)
2. Configure web app mode for your preferred URLs: [image]
3. Any time you open these URLs the will be in their own standalone window.  You can use bookmarks, or you can open one of the URLs from the command line:

   ```
    firefox https://app.example.com/
   ```

Comment: This extension works pretty well for me.  Clicking external URLs in the apps opens them in the main Firefox window as expected.  I'd like more options for position and height, eg 100 pixels from the left of the screen, 1500 pixels wide, full height of screen, largest monitor

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured out a way to do it as I want.

Enable the "Single Site Browser" feature in Firefox

1. In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button accepting the risk.
2. In the search box type `ssb`.
3. Double-click the `browser.ssb.enabled preference` to switch the from
   `false` to `true`

Launch the URL with the -ssb switch

type the following in a terminal:

```
firefox -ssb https://notion.so/
```

This works really well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported or working when reading the last posts [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283670)

Comment: @Carolus I'm not in Ubuntu or Firefox now to test and confirm. But have you tried this and found this to be not working? It was working when I posted this almost a year ago, not sure what changed after that.

Comment: Yeah. I tested this myself as well.

Comment: Still does not work on Firefox Ubuntu 22.04LTS. Shame.

Comment: Note that this feature has been removed, as of Firefox 86+: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1682593