# firefox in full screen mode

Tags: firefox

How to make firefox in fullscreen mode while opening it from the firefox icon. As i need to open an localhost webpage (bookmarked) by default, no need for address bar. Tried F11, AutoFullscreen(addon) but not sufficient.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/487936/how-do-i-open-fixed-window-in-firefox-like-chrome-app-mode

Comment: Sorry I dont think many (or any!) extensions that modify firefox itself that way work anymore, because of  the new permissions model at a guess... :-( (although the security benefits help!!)

Comment: Read about the so called kiosk mode of firefox, enter `firefox --kiosk` in a command line.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, it is possible by adding userChrome.css, refer  https://superuser.com/a/1269912
thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one of kiosk addons for Firefox. Here are some:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/sl/firefox/addon/mkiosk/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modern-kiosk/

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance, "https://addons.mozilla.org/sl/firefox/addon/mkiosk/" not supporting in my browser. I am using firefox quantum 62.0. "https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modern-kiosk/" in this addon still the mouse over animation for address bar working.